# Upload FIle limit

Tags: magento2

This is my code,I have create upload file in magento2 now i want to add upload file size limit. this is my code.

```
$uploader = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',['fileId' => "po_file"]);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf', 'docs', 'doc', 'docx']);

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();

    // $uploader->addValidateCallback("po_file", $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('admin/po_number'));
    $a = $result['file'];
    $this->_customerSession->setFilePath($a);
```

now any size image upload like 2 mb 3mb now i want restritc it to 2 mb

Comment: explain breifly

Comment: see my question updated

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you setup the upload but in PHP you can do stuff like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $maxsize    = 2097152;

    if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize)) {
        exit('File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.');
    }
}
```

On top of that you can use `php.ini` settings to limit the upload size:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to update your php.ini like below:

post_max_size = 8M

upload_max_filesize = 8M